# .htaccess wildcard redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i have to redirect many urls

the structure is this:

OLD URL

```
/category/product-18-name.aspx
```

NEW URL

```
product18name.php (is merely an example)
```

i wish to do a regex, if a user type `/anyword/product-18-name.aspx` i wish that user will go to `product18name.php`

in short, i wish that the word in the middle of 2 first slashes, example: `/category/` that maybe a real category or any word to go to right page

so a user that type: `/helloworld/product-18-name.apsx` goes to `product18name.php`
or `/sdjfkskfdns/product-18-name.apsx` goes to `product18name.php`

Now my .htaccess is full of 301 redirects, like

```
Redirect 301 /electronic/peacemaker2_a5f89948-9f15-4606-9d5c-051d84a4c070.aspx http://www.site.com/product.php?id_product=23580
```

any help ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

A rewrite rule to rewrite any-directory/product-18-name.aspx to product18name.php may look like this

> RewriteRule ^(.*)/product-18-name.apsx /product18name.php

Comment: Correct rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/product-18-name.apsx http://www.site.com/product18name.php [R=301,NC,L]` works like a charm! For example: `www.site.com/dhusjeufhu-gjurhgr--egjrh/product18.aspx` redirect correctly to `www.site.com/product18.php`

Comment: Im happy you did it :)